# ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter remove on the fly

Tags: java, netty

I have a Netty pipeline with several adapters, few of which should work only on the first arriving message. This means after processing the message I want to pass it forward and then remove the adapter from the pipeline. I have tried the following two approaches:
1. super.channelRead(ctx, msg);   THEN   ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
2. ctx.pipeline().remove(this);   THEN   super.channelRead(ctx, msg);

both of them work for now, but it's not clear to me whether there is any difference and is there any "best-practice" for using those.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both options are fine. The only difference is the time when the handler will be removed from the pipeline. In specific cases, it may have some effects on the execution flow. My own recommendation - remove the handler as soon as you don't need it or as soon as it performed all necessary operations.